# apt-cache --installed show lists packages that are not installed

Tags: apt

The `--installed` option does not appear to do anything. The man page isn't specific as to what is intended by its behavior, ie I can't tell if it either. For the applicable actions (presumably show and showpkg):

1. Only returns the version of the package that is installed
2. Only returns information for packages that are installed that match the query

In any case, it does not appear to do either of the above, instead returning the same output regardless of the option.

Comment: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=apt-cache+--installed and it's present in man apt-cache show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are explaining things wrong. That option is a modifier of the `rdepends` and `depends` commands:

> --installed
>       **Limit the output of depends and rdepends to packages which are currently installed.** Configuration
>       Item: APT::Cache::Installed

But then, it just don't show that, but is the list of the package that are installed, i. e.:

```
$ apt-cache depends kde-baseapps-bin 
kde-baseapps-bin
  Depends: kde-runtime
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libkdecore5
  Depends: libkdeui5
  Depends: libkfile4
  Depends: libkio5
  Depends: libkparts4
  Depends: libqt4-dbus
  Depends: libqt4-xml
  Depends: libqtcore4
  Depends: libqtgui4
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: kde-baseapps-data
  Breaks: <kcontrol>
  Breaks: <kcontrol:amd64>
  Breaks: kdebase-bin
  Breaks: <kdebase-bin:amd64>
  Breaks: <kdesktop>
  Breaks: <kdesktop:amd64>
  Replaces: kdebase-bin
  Replaces: <kdebase-bin:amd64>
  Conflicts: kde-baseapps-bin:amd64
```

As you can see, all the dependencies of the package, if I use `--installed`:

```
apt-cache --installed depends kde-baseapps-bin
kde-baseapps-bin
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libqt4-dbus
  Depends: libqt4-xml
  Depends: libqtcore4
  Depends: libqtgui4
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: libx11-6
```

Shorter, right? Out of all dependencies of that package, those are the only ones that I have installed. That's what the `--installed` modifier do, it do not list all the installed package.